# Avoid looping over arrays to get products of elements in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm currently converting some old fortran code into python and looking to use numpy-style operations as much as I can, for speed. 
The code calls for finding the products of all elements of two arrays, like so:

```
do i=1, nx
    do j=1, ny
       si(i,j) = xarray(i) * yarray(j)
    enddo
enddo
```

so instead I have vectorized it like so:

```
for i, x in enumerate(xarray):
    si[i] = x * yarray
```

but is there a way to remove that loop over x and generate the whole "nx x ny" array in one line, which would presumably be faster?

Comment: What happens when you try `si = xarray * yarray`?

Comment: That just produces another 1d array with elements x1*y1, x2*y2, x3*y3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `np.outer`

```
>>> nx = np.array([1,2,3,4])
>>> ny = np.array([2,3,4,5])
>>> np.outer(nx, ny)
array([[ 2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 4,  6,  8, 10],
       [ 6,  9, 12, 15],
       [ 8, 12, 16, 20]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
si = xarray.reshape(-1,1) * yarray
```